# Discrete Peaceful Encampments: Player 3 has entered the game!

Tags: geometry, chess, checkerboard

Here's a variation of [Discrete Peaceful Encampments: 9 queens on a chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78727/discrete-peaceful-encampments-9-queens-on-a-chessboard) (which itself is a variation of [Peaceful Encampments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78676/peaceful-encampments)).

> You have 4 white queens, 4 black queens, ***and 4 red queens***. Place all these pieces onto a normal 8x8 chessboard in such a way that no white queen threatens a black queen, no black queen threatens a red queen, and no red queen threatens a white queen (nor vice versa).

Can you find a way to place *more* than 4 queens of each color "peacefully" on an 8x8 chessboard?

Comment: Bonus puzzle: If you have 8 queens of each of the three colors, how big a checkerboard do you need, in order to place them all peacefully? 12x12? 11x11? Smaller?

Comment: No solution in $8+8+8$ on $10\times10$. See updated answer for $11\times11$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I'ma call it.

> There's no way to get more than 4 of every colour. Also, there is no simple way to prove this.

This is the most efficient way to do it:

> [image]

Notice how

> There's room for all kinds of shenanigans: You can add
>  * a white queen to e1 or a2
>  * a red queen to g2 or h7, and
>  * a black queen to e7, or
>  * *any* queen to g7, if you move a1 to a2 first
>  Annoyingly, adding any two colours always excludes every option of adding the third colour, no matter how much you shuffle the pieces around.

This way you can get

> any two colours to 5, but not all. Also, you could get white to 5 (e1) and red to 6 (g2, g7), but black still stays at 4, so you get a **4-5-6** solution.

In addition to all that:

> There's so much wiggle room in the above diagram, and you can get so very very close to a 5-5-5, that any simple impossibility proof (like "there aren't enough diagonals on the chess board") is not going to work.

This all is a result of feeding this problem into a highly sophisticated self learning neural network <sup>*</sup>, making it start from random (and later self-selected) positions, where every improvement path always led to this position, or one of its descendants, showing that this position is at least a local optimum.

<sup>*<sub>my brain</sub></sup>

Now all that is needed is

> a) a brute force solution proving that this is indeed the optimum, or
>  b) a 5-5-5 solution, or a simple proof of its impossibility.

If anyone can provide case b, I'll happily buy that person a beer, after a solid stint of banging my head against a wall.

Comment: A brute force solution shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: I have written a brute-force solver and confirm that you've found the optimum for an 8x8 grid. Unfortunately the solver is pretty complicated (in order to short-circuit parts of the search space) and so it's not what I would call a "simple proof." Plus, it takes about three minutes to run for 8x8, and is basically unusable as _any_ kind of "proof" for 9x9 and higher.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I too have written a solver, also confirming that there is no solutions with 10+10 or 5+5+5 on and 8x8 board. The run time for this is just a few seconds in an online debugging environment. I intend to modify it for the 'bonus puzzle' and for your 4-colors puzzle. If you are interested, the program is written in C.

Comment: @DanielMathias: I would be very interested to see it! Mine is (currently) at https://github.com/Quuxplusone/MetaSudoku/blob/master/discrete-encampments-3color.cc .

Comment: @Quuxplusone [Link here](https://onlinegdb.com/HkCbJYLQ4) It is an uncommented work in progress. Any changes I save will be reflected, as the link opens my source as 'read-only'

Answer (score 5):

5+5+4 and 6+5+4, but no 5+5+5

> The orange piece can be any color.
>  [image: queens]

for the bonus:

> One of the yellow square can the 9th queen of appropriate color, this then has $9+9+8$ on an $11\times11$ board.
>  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, I can do 4+4+4:

> ```
>  0 0 . . . . . .
>  0 0 . . . . . .
>  . . . . . . 1 1
>  . . . . . . 1 1
>  . . 2 . . . . .
>  . . 2 . . . . .
>  . . . . . . . .
>  . . . . 2 2 . .
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have obtained better results than those posted previously:

> I can place 4+4+8 queens on a 8x8, sorry for the basic formatting:
>
> ```
> ..22....
> ..22....
> ......33
> .......3
> ....3...
> 11......
> 11......
> ....3333
> ```
>
> I can also do 4+5+6 on a 8x8, which beats 4+5+5 ;)
>
> ```
> ..11...1
> ..1....1
> .......1
> ........
> 33......
> 33......
> ....222.
> .....22.
> ```

And for the bonus question:

> I can place 8+8+11 on 11x11:
>
> ```
> ...222.....
> ...222.....
> ...22......
> .........11
> ..........1
> ...........
> .33........
> 333........
> 333........
> ......1111.
> .......1111
> ```

Comment: Poker-wise, 4+5+5 beats 4+4+8; that's an interesting solution nonetheless. Your "9+9+9 on 11x11" got me all excited but unfortunately it seems wrong: the lower-right `1` diagonally attacks the upper-left `2`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone ah you are right. I had a bug in my program, thank you for spotting it! I can now do 8+8+11 on 11x11, so I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I can also do 4+5+6 which beats 4+5+5 :)

Comment: Any chance you could share your program and/or contact me offline with any further improvements you find to the data table in this post? https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/24/discrete-peaceful-encampments/

Comment: @Quuxplusone thank you for your blog link - very interesting. I am still enhancing my program, so not ready to release it just yet. I will let you know when I do. Meanwhile feel free to upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: @Quuxplusone well it took me some time, but I finally managed to finish it. I created a new OEIS sequence for this problem and added a link to this question and your blog: https://oeis.org/A328283. I have also released my code here: https://oeis.org/A250000. Enjoy!

Comment: Very cool! I see that you posted solutions for c=2 in https://oeis.org/A250000/a250000_2.txt. It might be useful to post a similar file for c=3 on https://oeis.org/A328283. I've made a new blog post based on your program for c>=4: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/10/18/discrete-peaceful-encampments-with-tables/

Comment: @Quuxplusone actually the solutions for c=3 are already there in https://oeis.org/A328283. Nice blog post! I am glad that someone is using my program for greater good. I was thinking of adding an OEIS entry for c=4 and linking to the current question, but I found c=4 rather boring - simply 4 armies that are completely symmetrical. Now c=5 is quite a bit more interesting...