# Peaceable Bishops on an 8x8 grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, chess

Place an equal number of red, white and black bishops on a 8x8 chess grid, such that no two bishops of different colours attack each other. What is the largest number of bishops you can place? Bonus question: can you add more bishops of one colour?

Here is a similar question with queens: [Discrete Peaceful Encampments: Player 3 has entered the game!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78801/discrete-peaceful-encampments-player-3-has-entered-the-game/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can this be improved?

> 14,14,16
>  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline A&C&A&&&B&C&B\\ \hline C&A&C&A&B&C&B&C\\ \hline A&C&A&&&B&C&B\\ \hline &A&&&&&B&\\ \hline &B&&&&&A&\\ \hline B&C&B&&&A&C&A\\ \hline C&B&C&B&A&C&A&C\\ \hline B&C&B&&&A&C&A\\ \hline \end{array}$$

Comment: That is a beautiful pattern! Could you add some grid lines, otherwise it is hard to see? Top left corner you can add another A.

Comment: @Dmitry Lacking vertical edge lines, but it is too much trouble to figure out the formatting on mobile. Also, the A was there in the top left, but MathJax ate it.

Comment: Daniel that looks great, thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I've searched for solutions with my own solver and I don't think this can be improved. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

This should be optimal, but haven’t proved it...

> [image]

Comment: aha yes... i thought it should only be triples...

Comment: Now I see a way to get 10 of each by modifying your solution... I'll look for further improvements before posting.

Comment: "Place an *equal* number of red, white and black bishops..."

Comment: Feel free to add more bishops of one colour