# Peaceable Bishops on a 10x10 grid version 2

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, chess

Can you place 42 bishops with 6 bishops for each of the 7 colors on a 10x10 grid, such that no two bishops of different colors attack each other?

Here are some similar questions:

[Peaceable Bishops on an 8x8 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91460/peaceable-bishops-on-an-8x8-grid)

[Peaceable Bishops on an 10x10 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91470/peaceable-bishops-on-an-10x10-grid/)

Comment: I sure hope you aren't going to do this with every possible grid size...

Comment: I think this one is too easy, finding the solution with almost no effort.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. You are right it was probably too easy. So I modified the problem.

Comment: @Quintec This will be the last one I promise :P

Comment: @RewanDemontay perhaps a 2x2x2x2x2x2 grid would be interesting ;)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Unless I'm mistaken, a bishop anywhere on a $2^N$ board controls (threatens or occupies) exactly half of the (hyper)squares, so maybe not all that interesting :-)

Comment: @Bass ah yes good point! Silly me.

Comment: Hmm, my earlier argument seems to be based on any even-dimensional diagonal direction counting as a valid direction for the bishop. If the movement is always constrained to a two-dimensional hypergrid slice instead, it seems to actually make for an entertaining exercise to count the maximum number of peaceable bishop encampments. :-)

Comment: Looks like people are sick of these puzzles. Ok I'll stop posting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was probably not the most exciting question. Anyway there are many solutions. Here are some examples:

> ```
> 723...5617
> 2.23456..1
> 32.......6
> .3......65
> .4......5.
> .5......4.
> .6.......4
> .1.....7.3
> 171654...2
> 71....4327
>
> 512...3.65
> 1.124.7.56
> 21....6...
> .2.....673
> .4........
> .3......4.
> 37......24
> 7.........
> 6..7342.51
> 5673..4.15
>
> 12.3..4671
> 21.5346..7
> .........6
> 35......64
> .3......4.
> ..........
> 467....253
> ...7..2..5
> 71.6..5..2
> 17.4..3521
> ```

Interestingly one cannot add a single other bishop of any color.